# SqlDependency permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, service-broker

The db is SQL Server 2012. All data tables are in the dbo schema. All data access is done via stored procedures in a different schema (user rt). I want to add query notifications for some tables, so I follow recommendations from these links: [Link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188311%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12862/Minimum-Database-Permissions-Required-for-SqlDepen):

```
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO rt;
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to rt;
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to rt;
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE to rt;
GRANT REFERENCES ON CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] TO rt;
GRANT RECEIVE ON [dbo].[QueryNotificationErrorsQueue] TO [rt];
```

The statement is `select Id, Name, UpdateDate from dbo.Reference`

The user RT has EXECUTE permission on the stored procedure and `SELECT` permissions on `dbo.Reference` table.

After `SqlDependency.Start` I can see a stored proc and a queue created in the RT schema. I can also see a new service created under ServiceBroker.

When I execute the SqlCommand with the user RT, I get an immediate notification with `Info = Invalid, Source = Statement.` If I execute the SqlCommand as SA, all works fine.

(Further research ([Link3](http://dimarzionist.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/how-to-make-sql-server-notifications-work/)) suggests that I need to grant CONTROL and IMPERSONATE from RT to DBO. This didn't fix the issue either.)

Do you have any suggestions on what might be going on?

Comment: Who is the owner of the new schema?