# Permissions using .NET SqlDependency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

SQLDependency Notifications work fine logged in as Windows Domain User, using Trusted Connection. But not as SQL-User:

I created a db login, user and role as follows:

```
CREATE LOGIN myLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'somePW', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
BEGIN CREATE USER myUser FOR LOGIN myLogin;
BEGIN CREATE ROLE "myRole" AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember N'myRole', N'myUser';
```

Furthermore, I added some permissions, following [this link](http://keithelder.net/2009/01/20/sqldependency-and-sql-service-broker-permissions/)

```
--Database level permissions
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE to [myRole];
GRANT CREATE QUEUE to [myRole];
GRANT CREATE SERVICE to [myRole];
GRANT SUBSCRIBE QUERY NOTIFICATIONS TO [myRole];
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO [myRole];

--Service Broker permissions
GRANT REFERENCES ON CONTRACT::[http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification] TO [myRole];
GRANT RECEIVE ON QueryNotificationErrorsQueue TO [myRole];
```

and also tried changing the db-owner as described in [this article](http://ardalis.com/SqlDependency-Issue-Resolved)

[This DBA-Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33082/sqldependency-permissions) ( aiming in the same direction ) does not provide any help.

The permissions to execute the query and do a select on the table by the SqlDependency are also set. I verified this using SSMS and execute the query with the user/pw-combination created above.

Now, I try to use the SqlDependency via .NET ( connection to DB is established with the login/user described above. Executing SqlDependency.Start( myConnectionString ) throws an exception ( translated from german ):

> The specified user 'owner' was not found.
>   Search the queue object 'SqlQueryNotificationService-9741490d-4f04-1f4e-AD70-b198e85b2812' is not possible because the object does not exist or you do not have the required permission.
>   Invalid object name 'SqlQueryNotificationService-9741490d-4f04-1f4e-AD70-b198e85b2812'.

Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: Is Service Broker enabled on the database?

Comment: @Jon Seigel - Sure it is. Sorry for not mention that. I added a line in the OP: "SQLDependency Notifications work fine logged in as Windows Domain User, using Trusted Connection. But not as SQL-User"

Comment: Okay. Do you see new Service Broker objects show up in the database like it says in the linked question? Also, does it work if you run this under `sa` or another SQL account that's `db_owner`?

Comment: No, there's no new queue in SB, executing as `myUser` from OP, what is strictly logical in my opinion, since `SQLDependency.Start(connectionString);` throws the error. If I use `sa` as SQL-User, everything works fine again. So i think, there is at least one permission missing. Any way to find out which?

Comment: There's something going on with permissions alright. In the error message, the user `owner` -- is that copied verbatim from the error or was that anonymized? Does that user mean anything to you? From the message, it seems like the code that's running isn't actually running under the security context you think it is.

Comment: The error log is copied. Thought the same, but if I debug the code, The parameter `connectionString` used calling `SqlDependency.Start()` is exactly defined in the form `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms224872%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Okay. I found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd195da8-93b2-43c6-8f59-674f5fb9d618/cannot-find-the-queue-sqlquerynotificationserviceguid

Comment: The only missing lines were `GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [SqlUser];` and `GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER::DBO TO [SqlUser];`After granting these permissions, nothing changed.

Comment: Well, after tracing everything with the SQLProfiler, I recognised the owner of the db-role ( the useraccount which didn't make it is associated to ) was set to an invalid value; whyever. changing this back to dbo made it work. Thanks for support @Jon Seigel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After days of debugging, one little setting made all the difference.

If you get this error mentioned in OP, please check the **owner of the DB-role** used! It wasn't set to `dbo` in my case. Changing that made it work - see comments for history!

Comment: I had the same issue. The user I am trying to login with is a sysadmin. Even though the user is a sysadmin I had to do this. You saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on Nico's answer, this query fixes the error:

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

The error message was

```
TableDependency.SqlClient.Exceptions.UserWithNoPermissionException: User without permissions.
```